# Converted pcap file not able to load in veloview

Tags: wireshark, paraview, pcap.net

I have captured udp log files. I can create the pcap file with captured udp data from log file using pcapDotnet but the newly created pcap files im not able to open veloview.exe. Tool itself getting crashed but same pcap files i can open in wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wireshark** captures and opens network-level traffic (meaning all kind of packets)

**Veloview** expects packets generated by Velodyne Lidars, with a specific dataformat (it runs at application level). Please check that your pcap file contains the original datapacket format.

For now, Veloview only reads Velodyne generated data, saved as legacy ".pcap" files (no .pcap.ng, and newer formats). So please try saving in this format.

Best regards,

Bastien Jacquet, VeloView Lead Developer

Comment: I'm having lidar data which captured from Velodyne through my own applcaition after that I'm converting the captured data into .pcap format using pcapdotnet but not able to load into veloview. But directly captured data from lidar through wireshark i can load it into veloview.

Comment: veloview is crashing with exception " Problem Event Name: APPCRASH and Exception Code:c0000005"

Comment: My understanding is that your code modifies the final content of the pcap files, and Veloview does not recognize it anymore.
Try comparing your generated pcap and the original one in wireshark to understand the differences.

Comment: Bastien Jacquest, thaks for your clarification, I found issue while converting into pcap file. While converting to .pcap file, i'm setting snapshot length as 0 after i reset to playload length, it started working.

Comment: Bastien Jacquest, Im getting an warning message like "Data packet from sensor  has un recognized factory byte (0x6f) veloview will interpret data packets and show points based on the XML calibration file only (Currently:16 lasers) ". how to resolve this? any hint?